# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_type_typname_nsp_index"

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I know that this question is already answered many times but i can't figured out what to do.
I'm using Postgres 14.7 ,NestJs and TypeOrm in my project.
I've created many entities, but for debugging purposes I use only one.
Here is my Entity:

```
import { Column, Entity, JoinTable, ManyToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Unique } from 'typeorm';
import { Supply } from './supply.entity';

@Entity({ name: 'Printers' })
@Unique(['model', 'manufacturer'])
export class Printer {
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;
    
    @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
    model: string;
    
    @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
    manufacturer: string;
    
    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
    description: string;
    
    @Column({ type: 'boolean', nullable: true })
    hasWifi: boolean;
    
    @Column({ type: 'boolean', nullable: true })
    hasUsb: boolean;
    
    @Column({ type: 'boolean', nullable: true })
    hasEthernet: boolean;
    
    @Column({ type: 'boolean', nullable: true })
    hasScanner: boolean;
    
    @Column({ type: 'boolean', nullable: true })
    hasFax: boolean;
    
    @Column({ type: 'boolean', nullable: true })
    hasUsbFlashDriver: boolean;
    
    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
    image: string;
    
    @Column({ type: 'double precision', nullable: true })
    price: number;
    //
    // @ManyToMany(() => Supply,supply => supply.printers)
    // supplies: Supply[];
}
```

Also, I use the Repository Pattern explained in here:
[NestJs TypeOrm Repository Pattern](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/sql-typeorm#sql-typeorm)

Here is my dataSource object.

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import * as Entities from '../../Entities';
import { Printer } from '../../Entities';

export const postgresProvider = [{
    provide: 'DATA_SOURCE',
    useFactory: async () => {
        const dataSource = new DataSource({
            database: process.env.DB_NAME,
            type: 'postgres',
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
            ssl: false,
            username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
            entities: [Printer],
            synchronize: true,
            logging: true,
        });
        return await dataSource.initialize();
        
    },
}];
```

As you can observe , I'm only importing the **Printer** Entity. So only the Printer Entity will be created.

The error I'm getting every time:

> [Nest] 7772  - 02/24/2023, 8:57:49 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader]
> DatabaseModule dependencies initialized +213ms [Nest] 7772  -
> 02/24/2023, 8:57:49 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ActionModule
> dependencies initialized +2ms query failed: CREATE TABLE "Printers"
> ("id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "model" character
> varying NOT NULL, "manufacturer" character varying NOT NULL,
> "description" character varying, "hasWifi" boolean, "hasUsb" boolean,
> "hasEthernet" boolean, "hasScanner" boolean, "hasFax" boolean,
> "hasUsbFlashDriver" boolean, "image" character varying, "price" double
> precision, CONSTRAINT "UQ_8457ad379d3c9921d912c31f169" UNIQUE
> ("model", "manufacturer"), CONSTRAINT "PK_882f70100101eba7cdd16e42e52"
> PRIMARY KEY ("id")) error: error: duplicate key value violates unique
> constraint "pg_type_typname_nsp_index" query: ROLLBACK [Nest] 7772  -
> 02/24/2023, 8:57:49 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] duplicate key value
> violates unique constraint "pg_type_typname_nsp_index"
> QueryFailedError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
> "pg_type_typname_nsp_index"
> at PostgresQueryRunner.query (C:\Users\Manager\Desktop\Workspace\src\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.ts:299:19)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at PostgresQueryRunner.executeQueries (C:\Users\Manager\Desktop\Workspace\src\query-runner\BaseQueryRunner.ts:651:13)
> at PostgresQueryRunner.createTable (C:\Users\Manager\Desktop\Workspace\src\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.ts:571:9)
> at RdbmsSchemaBuilder.createNewTables (C:\Users\Manager\Desktop\Workspace\src\schema-builder\RdbmsSchemaBuilder.ts:613:13)
> at RdbmsSchemaBuilder.executeSchemaSyncOperationsInProperOrder (C:\Users\Manager\Desktop\Workspace\src\schema-builder\RdbmsSchemaBuilder.ts:224:9)
> at RdbmsSchemaBuilder.build (C:\Users\Manager\Desktop\Workspace\src\schema-builder\RdbmsSchemaBuilder.ts:95:13)
> at DataSource.synchronize (C:\Users\Manager\Desktop\Workspace\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:329:9)
> at DataSource.initialize (C:\Users\Manager\Desktop\Workspace\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:267:43)
> at InstanceWrapper.useFactory [as metatype] (C:\Users\Manager\Desktop\Workspace\src\Endpoints\Database\data-source.ts:20:10)

Many people say that this error occurs because of the uuidv4 libary of the postgres.
Other say that (if i understood well enough) that postgres creates two tables . One for testing purposes and one for the development.
I've even commented out  all the fields in the printer entity and i've let only the **model** field. Same error.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you working with? This could happen if something attempts to either create the same table or re-use pre-generated identifiers for different relations, in concurrent sessions, without committing. You should normally get `ERROR:  relation "PK_882f70100101eba7cdd16e42e52" already exists` but it might not be happening because of visibility between transactions. Something could be "testing" your DDL in a separate session just to let the DB validate it - see [this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6125).

Comment: Postgres 14.7 is the version

Comment: @Zegarek I changed the database to SQL server express and again a similar error:                            **"Duplicate object instance with name "tableName".**

Comment: The SQL server error looks like a similar but not entirely the same problem. The root cause is likely the fact that something in your app is issuing these queries twice, in parallel. The github issue I linked seems related.